# Weird error trying to install Ruby Gems Before I can Install Rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm stuck trying to get the basic ruby gems installed so that I can move on and install rails on my machine. I've tried a few different things so I'm not sure if I've messed it up somewhere and now something is screwy as a result. I do have rvm installed and followed this path to get the gems up:

Installed RVM with this command:

> $ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Then This:

> $ rvm get stable

Then made sure to install the following from homebrew:

> $ brew install libtool libxslt libksba openssl

All where installed from my previous attempts.

I then tried to show RVM where openssl was located using this command and that's when things started going south (and since I've already failed to install rails earlier I knew it was a gem issue somewhere):

> rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/opt/openssl

When I run the command in my mac's terminal: "gem list"

I get back this:

```
> gem list
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in
> `read': Is a directory - /Users/ilyafeynberg/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
>   from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in
> `load_file'   from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in
> `initialize'  from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in
> `new'     from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in
> `do_configuration'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in
> `run'     from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Which is of course not right. As a result I'm stuck trying to figure out what gems are either misplaced, or where the error is. I'm getting many errors installing rails and I know it's because I don't have ruby and it's gems properly configured.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: why did you make `.gemrc` as a folder...?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how I managed to do this. I'm following Michael Hartl Ruby On Rails Tutorial, and while I have experience with Ruby (some) I have little with rails. I'll try and post the path. I do have rvm installed.

Comment: well thats what the error says - so remove it.

Comment: That did it! Was able to get around the remove error too. Thank you so much!!